# function that doesn't return the pointer to a list which is on another liste

Tags: c

so i wanted to manipulate a linked list that is in another list ; this is the structure , so we have the list abonnes that will contain a pointeur to the list liste_fav, we want to create a list of subscribers and for every subscriber we will add his list of favorite numbers because we want to manipulate it with adding numbers to it, edit it...

```
typedef struct liste_fav
{ // the list
       signed char numf[20];
       struct liste_fav *suiv;

}liste_fav;

    

/***********************************/

typedef struct abonnes
{ the principal list
    signed char  num_c[20];
    signed  char operateur [20];
    signed char profil[20];
    int credit;
    liste_fav liste;
    struct abonnes *adr;
}abonnes;
```

The principal structure is abonnes, and it contains a pointeur to liste_fav.

this function " acces-bum"  functions perfectly but!! So Its function is to return "pointe" a pointer to the structure where   the number num is supposed to be, and "prec" is the pointer that pointe to the structure before the structure where is the number, we need it for the deletion of a number is the liste_favthis function (bellow)  functions perfectly but!! So Its function is to return "pointe" a pointer to the structure where   the number num is supposed to be, and "prec" is the pointer that pointe to the structure before the structure where is the number, we need it for the deletion of a number is the liste_fav`enter code here`, ((prec)) doesn't get any changes , and when i tried the print its content it gives nothing , it blocks the execution for  seconds then it stops , so could anyone help please ( I want to return point and prec)

```
liste_fav *acces_num(abonnes *p, signed char *num, liste_fav *prec)
{
    //liste_fav ** precedent;

    liste_fav *point= &(p->liste);// pointeur of the num and we want to return it, we initialize it on the head of our liste_fav
    boolean trouv=false;

    while ((point != NULL) && (trouv==false))
    {
        if (strncmp(num,numero_fav_propre(point),20)==0)
            trouv=true;
        else
        {
            prec=point;// prec points to the structure that is before the structure where our num is supposed to be.

            point=suivant_fav_propre(point) ;
        }
    }
    if (trouv==true)
    {
     // return point if the value is found
        return (point);
    } //return null else
    else
        return NULL;

    }
```

((prec)) doesn't get any changes , and when i tried the print its content it gives nothing , it blocks the execution for  seconds then it stops , so could anyone help please ( I want to return point and prec)

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. Find help on formatting here https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help (And maybe try to translate a few more words to English.... ;-) )

Comment: The parameter `prec` is a _local_ copy of the pointer the caller gave. The caller's pointer cannot be modified in this way. You have to use a double pointer.

Comment: That is, `liste_fav **prec` and `*prec=point;`

Comment: But be careful that you don't corrupt the caller's list.

Comment: @Kiko - Although you wrote two times that _abonnes_ _contains a pointeur to liste_fav_, this is still untrue.